# Ember view - how to manipulate DOM after UI rendered without modifying the original source code?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

For some reasons, I can only add javascript after Ember application is created (i.e. all UI inited).

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="ember21643" class="ember-view form_field ticket_type_id has-ticket-type-field">
    <label for="">
    <script id="metamorph-249-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    Type
    <script id="metamorph-249-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    </label>
    <div id="zd_mn_385" class="zd-selectmenu zd-selectmenu-root zd-state-default">
        <button id="zd_mn_386" class="zd-selectmenu-base" role="button" tabindex="0" style="width: 131px; "><span class="zd-selectmenu-base-arrow zd-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span id="zd_mn_387" class="zd-selectmenu-base-content">-</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's easy to use jQuery to target the  to do direct DOM modification but I worry that it will break the Ember application.

Is there a proper way to change this view, for example:

- append/prepend a text to the div container
- change the  text to something else instead of "Type" as in the above example.

Using DOM inspection, this view looks like it can be accessed from:

```
Ember.View.views.ember21643
```

And

```
Ember.View.views.ember21643._childViews[0]
```

is pointing to "label". So I set

```
Ember.View.views.ember21643._childViews[0]._lastNormalizedValue = "ABC"
```

but it's still showing "Type" on the screen so probably this is not the way to do.

Please help. Thanks alot. (I'm new to Ember).

Comment: What do you mean by "without modifying the original source code?" Are you trying to write some JS code that interacts with a running ember application, but can't modify the source of that application?

Comment: @Michael: yes, that's exact what I'm trying to do. In addition to the above, I figured out that Ember.View.views.ember21643._childViews[0] is pointing to the "label". So I changed Ember.View.views.ember21643._childViews[0]._lastNormalizedValue = "ABC" but it's still showing "Type" on the screen... any thought?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i'm missing your point but, if I wanted to change the text in an ember view, I think I would use the Ember bindings.

## template

```
<div id="someView" type="text/x-handlebars">
  This sentence has a dynamic {{ end }}
</div>
```

## view

```
App.someView = Ember.View.extend({
  end : 'conclusion',
  templateName: 'someVIew' //not really necessary with new router to be explicit 
})
```

## view with binding

```
App.someView = Ember.View.extend({
  endBinding : 'contoller.end',
  templateName: 'someVIew' //not really necessary with new router to be explicit 
})
```

Does any of that help? :)

Comment: Actually I don't have access to the handlebar template. Let's say, a website is having ember app running. It loads my JS script afterward to add a heading text before the current text (the current text is rendered from app and now it is on screen), then change the current text to some description.